# Browser Based Text Editor Supporting Custom Math Mode Commands

Tags: text-editor, math, markdown, latex

What browser based text editor is there which allows me to

- render my writing in a scrollable area wiithout page breaks,
- supports some kind of math environment, e.g. TeX, LaTeX, KaTeX, MathJax, MathML, etc., and
- allows global definitions to be used in math mode across the document?

I found only [HackMD](https://hackmd.io/) so far, which is cool, but I wonder what else is there.

- As far as I can see, [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) only allows me to render pages, I assume this is a restriction of LaTeX itself?
- Same for [Typst](https://typst.app/)...
- [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) apparently supported global command definitions in version 4 but [stopped with version 5](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/1216).
- [Zettlr](https://www.zettlr.com/) apperently supports all of this but is not a browser tool.

Anything else?

Comment: Checkout [etherpad](https://etherpad.org) with [ep_mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_mathjax) plugin